# Razor VBHTML Page and Select Lists

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-webpages

I have a webpage (vbhtml) that is a single-page Razor with database content pulled.  I need to create 2 select lists that depend upon each other and am at a bit of a loss as to how to accomplish this even after reading a bunch of googled-articles.

```html
<form action="#" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Select Department</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="cboDept" name="cboDept">
                @Code selectQueryString = "SELECT Dept_Id, Dept_Desc FROM Departments WHERE Tag = '" & plantName & "'"
                    For Each row In ppaDepartments.Query(selectQueryString)
                End Code
                <option value="@row.Dept_Id">@row.Dept_Desc</option>
                @Code
                    Next
                End Code
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">Select Line</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="cboLine" name="cboLine">
                @Code 
                    Dim DepartmentID As Int32
                    Dim DepartmentDesc As String = Request.Form("cboDept")

                    DepartmentID = CInt(DepartmentDesc)

                    selectQueryString = "SELECT PL_Desc, PL_Id FROM Prod_Lines WHERE Dept_ID = " & DepartmentID
                    For Each row In ppaDepartments.Query(selectQueryString)
                End Code
                <option>@row.PL_Desc</option>
                @Code
                    Next
                End Code
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

That is my code in trying to get the Selected DEPT_ID out of the original cboDepartment dropdown value.  Obviously, it is wrong and won't post-back to allow me to grab that ID - but I can't figure out what to do to allow that to happen.

Comment: You include some javascript that handles the selection event in the first dropdown, queries the contents of the second dropdown for that value, and inserts the server's response in place of the second dropdown on the page.

Comment: sounds complicated..  I'm not great with JS yet, have mostly used asp.net / vb.net.  Normally I would have done this in a regular aspx page with code-behind, but this page is already built with Razor that I'm trying to get these dropdowns inserted into - hence the struggle.

Comment: Switch to [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) then.

Comment: You're on a bit of hiding to nothing working with VB in the old Web Pages framework. Examples for Web Pages are rare, and those that exist are almost exclusively in C#. Here's one I posted in 2012 that addresses your requirement.: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/196/webmatrix-jquery-cascading-dropdown-lists